# Detection logon, Locking Desktop, and login to windows7 & 8using nodejs

Tags: windows, node.js

I am going to perform some login, logout operations with node js, but I'm not getting whether there are any modules which I can directly interact with my system and know login status, and perform login and logout operations?

Comment: @alandarev, as nodejs is build with C++, we can do all those things with node js which c++ can do. we just need proper addon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer,
I done it with pythonshell module of nodejs, and some python code,

```
import ctypes 

user32 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("user32.dll") 
user32.LockWorkStation()
```

And also we can do it with nodejs only with ffi module.

By using ffi module, we can call functions inside dll. The same way here I used with python.